# Using variables in toggleClass

Tags: jquery

```
var togglevalue = 'someclassname';

$("#element").toggleClass(togglevalue);
```

I have been trying to use a variable to specify toggleClass but jquery does not seem to recognize this as a variable. Help pls? I have tried '' "" etc.

Comment: This code sould work as is. If it doesn't, then there is some logical mistake in what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake in some other part of code because this code is working. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ypj8/1/)**

Maybe you don't well understand how "toggleClass" works.

Supposing you have (*):

```
<div id="element">..</div>
```

Calling

```
$("#element").toggleClass(togglevalue);
```

You add attribute "class='someclassname'" to $("#element") if class someclassname is not present, otherwise class someclassname will be removed.

So, starting from (*) situation:

```
$("#element").toggleClass(togglevalue);
<div id="element" class="someclassname">..</div>
$("#element").toggleClass(togglevalue);
<div id="element" class="">..</div>
```

Another dummy and frequent mistake could be call .toggleClass from $("#element") [id-selector] instead of $(".element") [class-selector]. For example, if you have:

```
<div class="element">..</div>
```

and call

```
$("#element").toggleClass(togglevalue);
```

obviously nothing happens!

Comment: `Another dummy and frequent mistake could be call .toggleClass from $("#element") [id-selector] instead of $(".element") [class-selector]` How does that affect anything? They're both jQuery collections, so how would it make a difference?

Comment: if you have <div class='element'/> and you call  $("#element").toggleClass('x') nothing happens, maybe I have badly explained..

Comment: Oh, I see. Your updated explanation is much better. :)